# LCC Electrum Wallet Set Up With Ledger Nano S Cannot Find Private Keys, Sweep or Generate Seed

Tags: electrum

I have a problem with Electrum LCC Wallet. I set up the wallet using Ledger NANO S and seems it somehow attached itself to the LTC wallet in Ledger. I get this message every time I want to send LCC from the Electrum wallet.

error: {'message': 'the transaction was rejected by network rules.\n\n16: mandatory-script-verify-flag-failed (Signature must use SIGHASH_FORKID)\n[ ... really long body of hashed content ... ]', 'code': -1}

Since it was initiated with Ledger NANO S I have no way to see private Keys, Sweep or Generate a Seed. Im stuck with a handful of LCC which I want to move. I tried restoring the wallet with no luck as the info I need is encrypted in Ledger. How can I find private key or seed to restore, thank you.